# Split array element to two column

Tags: php, arrays, split

Please help me below PHP code:

I have array below:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "tile"=> "title 1",
        "description" => "description 1"
    ),
    array(
        "tile" => "title 2",
        "description" => "description 2"
    ),
    array(
        "tile" => "title 3",
        "description" => "description 3"
    )
);
```

And I want output HTML as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS & JS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 class_1">
            <div class="title">
                title 1
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                title 2
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                title 3
            </div>                        
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 class_2">
            <div class="description">
                description 1    
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                description 2    
            </div>
             <div class="description">
                description 3    
            </div>                       
        </div>
    </div>
</div>     
</body>
</html>
```

How to use foreach to loop and split title and description in two colum (title 1, title 2, title 3 **in only one class title**, and description 1, description 2, description 3 **in only one class description**), output as below:

```
title 1  |  description 1
-------------------------------
title 2  |  description 2
-------------------------------
title 3  |  description 3
-------------------------------
```

And if **description 1** or **description 2** is **empty**, I want output as:

```
title 1  |  description 2
-------------------------------
title 2  |  description 3
-------------------------------
title 3  |
-------------------------------
```

( "**Description 2**" can fill into position of "**Description 1**" if "**Description 1**" is empty )

or

```
title 1  |  description 1
-------------------------------
title 2  |  description 3
-------------------------------
title 3  |
-------------------------------
```

And finally, how to archieved this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 class_1">
            <div class="title">
                title 1
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                title 2
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                title 3
            </div>                        
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 class_2">
            <div class="description">
                description 1    
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                description 2    
            </div>
             <div class="description">
                description 3    
            </div>                       
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.
Thank you so much.

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 0):

Split the arrays up before looping.

```
<?php
   $titles = array();
   $description = array();
   foreach ($array as $value) {
       if ($value['tile']) {
          $titles[] = $value['tile'];
       }
       if ($value['description']) {
          $descriptions[] = $value['description'];
       }
   }
?>
<?php foreach ($titles as $i => $title): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 class_1">
           <div class="title">
              <?php echo $title ?>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 class_2">
           <div class="description">
              <?php if (isset($descriptions[$i])): ?>
              <?php echo $descriptions[$i]; ?>   
              <?php endif; ?>  
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. But <div class="row"> repeat too, and if "description 1" is empty, "description 2" can't instead of postion of "description 1".

Comment: In your question it looks like you want one row per array entry, so you need `<div class="row">` to repeat on every array entry. You're right, though, that I mis-read your requirements for missing descriptions. I'll try to edit.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Your code nice. But "Description 2" not fill into position of "Description 1" if "Description 1" is Null or empty.

Comment: @john_doe you could change `if ($value['description'])` to `if (!empty($value['description']))`

Comment: @scrowler. Actually i will replace title with a checkbox, if 'checkbox 1' is checked, show 'description 1' and if 'checkbox 1' is not checked, hide 'description 1' with jquery, and after 'description 1' hiden, "description 2" will fill into exactly position of "description 1". If with <div class="row"> loop in code, "description 2" can not fill into position of "description 1". Any solution for this. Many thanks.

Comment: If "Description 1" is null or empty, then ($value['description']) returns false, so $descriptions does not get anything added to it in that iteration. In that case, the first element in $descriptions will be "Description 2". So on the first pass through outputting the HTML, $titles[0]` will output "Title 1 and $descriptions[0] will output "Description 2."

Comment: @john_doe My answer does what you asked for (see my comment directly above about how Description 2 will fill in next to Title 1, if Description 1 is empty). But your comment about using jQuery to show and hide parts would really be a separate question. I suggest you re-write or ask a new question.